# Conditional groupby in multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, group-by, conditional-statements

I would like to group arrays in the following fashion:

```
a = np.array([ ['A', 1], ['man', 1], ['walks', 0], ['down', 0], ['the', 2], ['street', 2] ]) 
# would like the output to be:
b = np.array([ ['A man', 1], ['walks', 0], ['down', 0], ['the street', 2] ])
```

Wherein the array is grouped to adjacent items which have the same item in one row or column, but only for certain types of conditions and not others.

In my case, I have a null or zero type of condition, which should be ignored, with groupings occurring for all other types.

I have tried some variations of `itertools.groupby` by I have not figured out how to leave the zero case alone.

Comment: Why not just use `filter` or add a function that converts the values to a list (`[v for  k, v in it.groupby(*args) if len(v)`), depending if you want lisp-ishness or idiomatic Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pandas is a good option in this case

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ ['A', 1], ['man', 1], ['walks', 0], ['down', 0], ['the', 2], ['street', 2], ]) 

# make np array into pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['word', 'group'])

# groupby the group column, ignoring the 0 group
word_groups = df[df['group'].astype(int) != 0].groupby('group', as_index=False)

# aggregate words in same group
joined_groups = word_groups.aggregate(lambda x: ' '.join(x))

# add the zero group back in
joined_groups.append(df[df['group'].astype(int) == 0])
```

[image]

if you want an np array back from a pandas dataframe, just use the `.values` property

Comment: This would be a good solution in some cases.  I'm loading many arrays like this so I don't know how much overhead it would cause from having data frames created each time. In addition, I am hoping to preserve the sequence.

Comment: I think that there are definitely ways to that with pandas, but perhaps that's different enough to be a new question? You're right this solution would not be ideal for that, though it answers original question

Answer (score 1):

I have a stupid answer. I am pretty sure that someone will come up with some amazing answers. But hope this will help you.

```
def combine_adjacent(lst):
    new_lst = []
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i][1] == lst[i+1][1] and lst[i][1] != '0' and lst[i][1] != None:
            new_lst.append([lst[i][0]+' '+lst[i+1][0], lst[i][1]])
        elif lst[i][1] == '0':
            new_lst.append(lst[i])
    return np.array(new_lst)
```

input

```
a = np.array([ ['A', 1], ['man', 1], ['walks', 0], ['down', 0], ['the', 2], ['street', 2] ])
combine_adjacent(a)
```

Output

```
array([['A man', '1'],
   ['walks', '0'],
   ['down', '0'],
   ['the street', '2']], 
  dtype='<U10')
```

Comment: This solution works well for the case of two columns, but it would be great if there is a way to generalize the solution to join across elements when the number of columns is large.

Comment: Sure, it  can be better. What I wrote is just a sample code. You can optimize it in your own way. That's the beauty of programming. Isn't it?